# "Open Recent" in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Does Emacs have the capability to open recent files (e.g. a menu like File > Open Recent...)?

I know that Aquamacs, for OS X, has this feature. But is it common to all Emacs versions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ordinary GNU Emacs doesn't have a menu showing recently open files. However, all Emacs commands have history, including `find-file` (`C-x C-f`). Selecting “File | Open” in the menu or opening a file with `emacsclient` also adds to this history. After you press `C-x C-f`, press `up` and `down` to navigate the history of opened files.

The history is saved between sessions if you enable session saving with the `desktop` package.

Comment: Good old find-file is replaced by `ido-find-file` by most folks knowingly or unknowingly. The history of ido is a completely different business. recentf might be a better solution here.

Comment: However, this history is erased after you close emacs.

Comment: @fiacobelli Hence my suggestion to use the `desktop` package.

Comment: @Gilles yes. I missed that last line.

Comment: A simpler answer is to just use (savehist-mode 1) in .emacs ...
See cueben's answer for details.

Comment: @Jaseem You're right, **but** all is not lost: in `ido-find-file` if you do `C-x C-f` again it drops you back to good old `find-file` and (AFAICS) the `up`/`down` history is accessible there (even for files previously found via `ido-find-file`).

Comment: Instead of using `up` and `down` arrow keys is it possible to make keybinding for `C-n` (down), `C-p` (up) ? @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'

Comment: @alper Yes. By default `M-p` and `M-n` do the same thing as `up` and `down`, while `C-p` and `C-n` retain their usual meaning of moving between lines (in case the minibuffer has multiple lines, which doesn't normally happen with a file name but can happen with other things such as a search string). But you can change the bindings in `minibuffer-local-map`.

Comment: I have added: `(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-n") 'next-history-element)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-p") 'previous-history-element)` which does not show cycle behavior as `up`, `down` keys @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'

Comment: @alper Works for me with Emacs 24.5.

Answer (score 39):

The most idiomatic method of providing this functionality that I know of is through the use of `recentf-mode` (more [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles)).  I enable it in my initialization file with:

`(require 'recentf)`

`(recentf-mode 1)`

It then provides an interactive function, `recentf-open-files`, which I bind to `C-x f`, which provides a numbered menu of recently opened files that spans sessions, i.e. even if you shut down emacs and restart it, it will retain your recently opened files.  You can bind the function to an accelerator with another line in your initialization file, like:

`(global-set-key "\C-xf" 'recentf-open-files)`

(Optional)

If you make extensive use of Tramp, recentf will track those files too, and do it's periodic cleanup thing which can be a real mess since the files are remote.  Prevent this by putting this in your startup file:

`(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 'never)`

Comment: I'd advocate against binding recentf to 'C-x f'. Its what you need to open a specific file, which may or maynot be in our history. If you have ido enabled, use `ido-find-file` for fuzzy matching and speed. So in my case, its "C-x C-f" mapped to `ido-find-file` and "C-x C-r" bound to `recentf-open-files

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to save the minibuffer history between emacs invocations you can put the following in your .emacs:

(savehist-mode 1)

Unlike the desktop package that can save all your open buffers across invocations, this does just the minibuffer history (e.g. when opening a file you can use the up arrow to navigate the list of files you opened in a previous session).

Comment: I think this is the best solution! You don't need desktop. In fact you probably don't want all the buffers to be saved...

Answer (score 5):

GNU Emacs *does* include library `recentf.el`, since Emacs 22. Just do as indicated by R.P. Dillon.

Comment: When to use recentf, when savehist? Savehist stores files too. Confusing.

Comment: @RichieHH: Why this comment to my answer. My answer says nothing about savehist. The two are different, and have different use cases. If those differences aren't clear to you then consider asking a question about that.